# How to securely make login system in hybrid app (phonegap/cordova)

Tags: android, ios, cordova, webview, uiwebview

Apparently you can't use cookies to store your Sessions or JWTs in iOS's UIWebView / Android's WebView. After looking it up online, it seems like the accepted solution is to store it in LocalStorage. This obviously has serious XSS implications, as secure and sensitive information is not supposed to be stored in LocalStorage.

Has someone figured out a secure way to implement a login system in a hybrid app that stores either the Session identifier or JSON Web Token? I'm surprised that there are no good resources on this.

Comment: Try storing it in Android's shared preferences?  Those can only be read by your application, unless the phone is rooted.

Comment: How is that any more secure than LocalStorage?

Comment: Its more secure than a desktop cookie, which can be read by any app on the computer.  There's a limit on how secure things can be on a client you don't physically control.

Comment: Thank you for trying to help me, but that is an insanely preposterous claim. Take a look at [this](https://www.owasp.org/index.php/HTML5_Security_Cheat_Sheet#Local_Storage) why.

Comment: No, its not.  A cookie is a file stored on a PC.  I can point you to the directory.  Any app on the client PC can edit it.  Its not actually secure at all. You seem to not understand the difference between web apps and real apps and the security models of actual devices.

Comment: Did you read the link I send you? LocalStorage is not supposed to be used for sensitive information. You seem to not understand the idea behind an  httpOnly cookie (not that it's enough to stop XSS in itself, but still)

Comment: I read it.  You don't understand that XSS doesn't exist on a local machine on an app running locally.  The security threats and risks are different.  Start using critical thinking and not links that you're obviously regurgitating rather than understanding.

Comment: Yes, it is obviously a different environment. But for you to say that XSS threats don't exist on mobile is ridiculous. Of course it is much more controlled in an app so there is such a slim chance of it happening. But there are still ways. My apologies for not using critical thinking (aka blindly listening to you with no links or examples)

Comment: I don't say they don't exist on mobile, I say they don't exist on a local app running on mobile.  Because the data is coming from the local machine, and not even possible to get at without being code on the local machine.  But I'm done trying to educate you.

Comment: The data is not coming from a local machine in a hybrid app. Hybrid apps typically use ajax calls from a remote server.

Comment: And my suggestion, if you read it initially, was to store it on the local machine and grab it from there.  That's one of the reasons why you make an app hybrid-  so you can use local advantages like secure storage.  If you aren't, don't bother with an app-  just write a website.

Comment: Also, every app uses webservice calls-  hybrid or not.  THey store the token on the filesystem.  The one has nothing to do with the other.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/129709/discussion-between-lazyboy78-and-gabe-sechan).

Answer (score 1):

I use a token that is returned after the user logs in. It is generated on the server sided and stored in the database. Then it is also stored in local storage, and expires after a set amount of time. I then include that as a header with all of the future API calls.